SSRS - Subreport could not be shown
I have this error and no idea why it happends :
Error: Subreport could not be shown.
The subreport works well alone.
But when I call it from a parent report ... I have the error.
Do you know how this is possible ?
Three text parameters are passsed from the parent to the subreport. Same name and type for all.

You'll probably need to edit your question and show the subreport setup including all the parameters. Also include the subreport's available values for each parameter, if you have specified a list of available values and the master report is passing in a value from outside that list, the subreport will fail.
